# How to migrate a Complex Type to the .net Core Service Implementation

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core

My first time using .net core.

I was able to build a functioning ,net core web application that calls data from my SQL server using Onion Layers. My layout is as below:

```
Architecture
  Core
     Application Services
     Domain Services
  Core.Entity
Infrastructure
UI
  API
     CemeteryAPI
  Web
     MVC Web Application
```

My HomeController has a PageModel with a Complex Type of Search, which consists of about 5 or so ints another 5-6 Lists.  In the past I would have done:

```
var model = new Models.HomePageModel
     {
        Search = new Business.Search()
     };

public partial class Search
{
    public String Surname { get; set; }
    public String Forename { get; set; }
    public String Initials { get; set; }
    //etc.
}
```

I have registered my Services on my startup in ConfigureServices and have attempted to inject this way

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddScoped<ICemeteryRepository, CemeteryRepository>();
    services.AddScoped<ICountryRepository, CountryRepository>();
    //etc
    services.AddScoped<ICemeteryService, CemeteryService>();
    services.AddScoped<ICountryService, CountryService>();
}
```

CemeteryService

```
   //ApplicationService
   public class CemeteryService : AbstractUnitOfWorkService, ICemeteryService
   {
    public CemeteryService(IUnitOfWork uow) : base(uow) { }

    public int Count()
    {
        return _unitOfWork.CemeteryRepository.Count();
    }

    public Cemetery Get(int id)
    {
        return _unitOfWork.CemeteryRepository.Get(id);
    }

    public List<Cemetery> List()
    {
        return _unitOfWork.CemeteryRepository.GetAll().ToList();
    }
}
```

ICemeterRepository

```
//DomainService
public interface ICemeteryRepository : IRepository<Cemetery>
{
}
```

CemeteryRepository

```
public class CemeteryRepository : BaseRepository, ICemeteryRepository
  {
    public CemeteryRepository(SAWGPDBContext context) : base(context) { }

    public int Count()
    {
        return _context.Cemetery.Count();
    }

    public Cemetery Get(int id)
    {
        return _context.Cemetery.Find(id);

    }

    public IEnumerable<Cemetery> GetAll()
    {
        return _context.Cemetery;
    }

   //etc
}
```

ICemeteryInterface

```
public interface ICemeteryService
{
    int Count();
    List<Cemetery> List();
    //etc
}

public ActionResult Index([FromServices] ICasualtyService _CasualtyService, IPhotoService _PhotoService, ICountryService _CountryService, ICemeteryService _CemeteryService, IRegimentService _RegimentService)

        var model = new Models.HomePageModel
        {
            Search = new SearchPageModel(_PhotoService, _CasualtyService,  _CountryService, _CemeteryService, _RegimentService, )
        };
```

This looked wrong but I couldn't find any proper examples as I wasn't sure what to look for exactly.  The above returns

> Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must
>   have a parameterless constructor.

I presume I need to build a SearchService but I'm not entirely clear how to build one for a complex type.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure what your `ConfigureServices` looks like, but I don't understand why you have so many different services? To me it looks like those are the SQL table names passed along for injection... It's quite difficult to properly answer you based on what you have shown so far in your question...

Comment: Your comment makes me think I missed something major.  I did all this by using the below project as a template...its specifially for webapi and has no webapp aspect so i had to guess....https://github.com/EASV/CSharpCleanRestWithEFCore2018